What's the Best Algorithm for Handling Discrete and Continuous Controls in Action Spaces?
I'm working on an optimization problem involving the control of vehicle displacement over time.
My current setup consists of vehicle displacements [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, ...] recorded at consistent time intervals, with each measurement corresponding to a fixed velocity of 100 km/h. I've been optimizing these displacement values using the DDPG (Deep Deterministic Policy Gradient) algorithm.
Now, I want to expand my optimization to include velocity as well. So the action can be structured like:
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]

[a, b, c] at velocity x,
[d, e, f] at velocity y
[g, h, i] at velocity z

I am considering three different scenarios for the velocity action space:

Discrete Velocity Space: The velocity can only take on specific values, such as [x, y].
Continuous Velocity Space (with bounds): The velocity can vary continuously around specified values, such as [x ± some value, y ± some value].
Fully Continuous Velocity Space: The velocity can take on any value
within a certain range.

For all of this a,b,c,d .... are all form continious action space [-1,1] for example.
What is best algorithm for this.
